# Invoke Amazon Forecast API from R

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, forecasting, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-forecast

I see that we can call Amazon Forecast from Python, examples

[Multiple models comparison](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-forecast-samples/blob/master/notebooks/5.%20Getting_started_with_AutoML.ipynb)

[How to use Amazon Forecast](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-forecast-samples/blob/master/notebooks/5.%20Getting_started_with_AutoML.ipynb)

Anyone knows how can we do the same with R?

I want to call Amazon Forecast to run all the different 8 models from R.

Answer (score 0):

If you Amazon Forecast is already trained and you have and endpoint available you can use httr and jsonlite to interact with it.